# Problem with String Verbatim

Tags: c#, string

I use C#.

I need assign a value to a `string as verbatim`.

Here my code:

```
string verbatim = "@<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">";
```

or

```
string verbatim = @"<META NAME=""ROBOTS"" CONTENT=""NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"">";
```

But it does not work.

What I'm doing wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean a verbatim string literal? Double-up the internal quotes and move the `@`:

```
string verbatim = @"<META NAME=""ROBOTS"" CONTENT=""NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"">";
```

Answer (score 3):

The @ charctaer goes outside the string ath beginning and you need to escape your quotes, i.e.

```
string verbatim = @"<META NAME=""ROBOTS"" CONTENT=""NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"">"
```

Comment: I tried with your version but I still have the same problem starting on ROBOTS any idea?

Comment: Yes, apologies you have to use doubled quotes in a verbatim string.

Answer (score 1):

The @ must be outside the string and you need to use double quotes:

```
string verbatim = @"<META NAME=""ROBOTS"" CONTENT=""NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"">";
```